# Susy Compass omega is adding #margin-left: -1em;

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I am using the Susy framework to create a grid for my website and am really liking it. 
I can't figure out why #margin-left: -1em is being added when I use omega in span columns. 
I cannot seem to find any information about it and it throws this error when I validate the css:    .second Parse Error #margin-left: -1em;

My code looks like the below

```
//this is the default number of columns
$total-columns: 12; 
//width of each column
$column-width   : 4em; 
//space between columns
$gutter-width   : 1em; 
//space on the right and left of the grid
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;

.first{
    @include span-columns(6,12);
}
.second{
    @include span-columns(6 omega,12);
}
```

and generates this

```
.first {
   width: 49.15254%;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 1.69492%;
   display: inline;
}

.second {
   width: 49.15254%;
   float: right;
   margin-right: 0;
   #margin-left: -1em;
   display: inline;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code compiles fine for me with Compass. The line in question has an asterisk, not a hashmark:

```
*margin-left: -1em;
```

A line of CSS that starts with asterisk is a hack that works only for IE <= 7.

To disable IE 6-7 support, set `$legacy-support-for-ie` to false prior to importing Susy:

```
$legacy-support-for-ie: false;
@import "susy";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's strange, not sure why mines compiling down to a # rather than a *. I will disable support for IE 6-7 and re add the code manually if need be.

Comment: It changed from `#` to `*` in the latest release. See [this commit](https://github.com/ericam/susy/commit/0c11935559a5ff1a20d8800499028ca120a3baf3). IE rounds up when it hits sub-pixel math, so layouts can break unless you give them extra room to breathe. `-1em` gives them that room, and since the `omega` element is floated right, most people don't even notice. You can turn off any hacks using the Compass [browser support](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/support/) settings: `$legacy-support-for-ie6`, `$legacy-support-for-ie7`, or the more general `$legacy-support-for-ie`.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help and explanation. Ive upgraded to latest version of Susy and its showing the * now.